# How to start external AS file playing on frame 2 (instead of frame 1)

Tags: actionscript

I am using actionscript 3 and I have used an external actionscript file (.as) for my game.

I would like the external actionscript file to be played at frame 2 (instead of frame 1, as it is an introductory page of the game) on the timeline.

How do I do that? I have been trying and looking for answers for hours, appreciate if you can help on this. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the Flash IDE?

If your file isn't an Actionscript class, just use the `include` statement. Eg. on frame 2, write:

```
include "myFile.as";
```

If you're using classes, there's an option in the Actionscript-3 settings, where you can specify a frame where classes should be imported to. So if your class is `MyClass`, just call something like this on frame 2:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

Maybe you'll even want a combination of the above.. eg. export all classes to frame 2 and also `include` an initialization script on frame 2.

Comment: thanks for ur reply!

I have tried your second method, my file name is color_match so is it right that the code is var MyInstance = new color_match();  ? 

But I got an error msg: Error: Error #2136: The SWF file contains invalid data.
 at color_match/frame2()

what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: @Nail How does your color_match file look like? Does it purely contain a class definition? Where is it located? Did you set the source-path in the actionscript properties?